# Model Counting for Sum of Conjunctive Formulas

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, counting

### Problem:

Let $X=\{x_1, ..., x_N \}$ be a set of binary variables. Each variable can be assigned to either $0$ or $1$ so there are $2^N$ possible assignments.

**Input:** We are given a positive integer $C$ and a set of binary functions $F=\{f_1,...,f_M\}$ where each function is defined as a simple conjunction of some subset of $X$. That is, each $f_i \in F$ is defined as $f_i(X) := \prod_{x \in X'}x$ for some $X' \subseteq X$.

**Output:** The number of assignments to variables in $X$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^M f_i(X) = C$.

### Question:

Do you know of a polynomial-time algorithm that solves this problem for a bounded value of $C$?

Any ideas or pointers to references would also be greatly appreciated.

It is OK if the complexity is bounded with respect to e.g. some constant $D$ which could be the maximum size of $X'$, that is, the maximum number of variables in the product of any function $f_i \in F$.

### Observations:

When $|X'|=1$, that is, when each function $f_i \in F$ can only have one variable, then the problem can be reduced to the counting version of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and can be solved in $\mathcal{O}(N\cdot C)$ time using an modified version of a [dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) for solving subset sum.

Comment: What can you say about the case $C = 0$?

Comment: At first, I thought it was trivial (one solution is $X = \{0,...,0\}$), but I realize there could be multiple solutions. Therefore I think it's an interesting case.

Answer (score 1):

When $C = 0$ and each $f_i$ depends on two inputs, your problem is equivalent to #2-MONOTONE-SAT, which is #P-complete, see for example [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14532/what-are-the-p-complete-subfamilies-of-2-sat) on [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com).